# localStorage of javascript gives me as a result "null"

Tags: javascript, null

After using following commands,

```js
  localStorage.setItem('message', 'hi'); 
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('message'));
```

the console says me `null`. I think I did the command right. But it does not work. How can I fix it?

I tried a lot of things starting off on the syntax rule, then I checked if the position was right and also the command by itself, but it always gave me `null` as a result, I'm following a youtube tutorial and they are getting it right but I don't.

Comment: These two statements, by themselves, are working for me.  (Both on a web page and directly in the browser console.)  How specifically are you executing these?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: There is no error with your code. Maybe you can post more code you have written.

Comment: you can confirm if it's saved at Developer Tools > Application > Storage > (your page).
You should see your key:value there

Comment: It feels like you're running these in async operations. Can you share how you use them?

Answer (score 1):

Pietro! The code that you've provided looks correct, assuming that...

1. You are using a modern browser
2. The code is running, one command after another, in the browser console
3. You have cookies enabled

Local Storage is a privacy-sensitive feature, so if your browser has cookies disabled, it might not be working correctly. (For instance, *Safari* will usually give you a warning that the operation you are requesting isn't secure, though I'm not sure about other browsers).

If you are using these commands in any other context, please provide them here! For instance, if you are using an older browser, you could provide the version number. If you are running these functions as part of a web script, instead of in the console, that will be important, too.

Hope this helps!